# redefinition of 'init' actions on introducing import

Tags: antlr4

My parser consists of several rules, most of them starting with @init action. Now as my file had become extremely large I decided to make a separate file LexerRules.g4 for lexer rules and used

```
grammar TermParser;
import LexerRules;
```

Now if I use my alias ANTLR4; I would encounter the following error(s).

```
error(94): TermParser.g4:163:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:189:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:200:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:212:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:230:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:296:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:315:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:359:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:381:1: redefinition of 'init' action
error(94): TermParser.g4:440:1: redefinition of 'init' action
```

How does my separating the parser and lexer rules have anything to do with the using of @init action in multiple parser rules ?

I encountered no problem when I had one big file for everything: lexer as well as parser rules.

Also, the import is not making the main grammar file in ANTLRWORKS 2 to get rid of the implicit definition warning.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem